# UWP - Custom Undo and Redo on InkToolbar on a InkCanvas - System.ExecutionEngineException was unhandled

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, inkcanvas

Trying to create a custom undo and redo on the `InkCanvas`. However after some stress testing (add a lots of strokes, undo and redo a lots of times), the app crashes with:

> System.ExecutionEngineException was unhandled. HResult=-2146233082

on the foreach loop of my `AddToRedoList` method.  Anyone have any ideas how to catch and fix the exception?

```
private void AddToRedoList(InkStroke addStroke) {
  var addInkPoint = addStroke.GetInkPoints();
  var addInkPointList = new List<InkPoint>();
  foreach (var point in addInkPoint) {
    addInkPointList.Add(new InkPoint(point.Position, point.Pressure));
  }

  redoCustomStrokeList.Add(new CustomStroke() {
    InkPoints = addInkPointList,
    DrawingAttributes = addStroke.DrawingAttributes
  });
}

private void UndoOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  var allStrokes = InkImage.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();
  var undoStroke = allStrokes[allStrokes.Count - 1];
  AddToRedoList(undoStroke);

  allStrokes[allStrokes.Count - 1].Selected = true;
  InkImage.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.DeleteSelected();
}

private void RedoOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  var lastRedoInkPoints = redoCustomStrokeList[redoCustomStrokeList.Count-1];
  InkImage.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.AddStroke(CreateStroke(lastRedoInkPoints));
    redoCustomStrokeList.Remove(lastRedoInkPoints);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the whole reproduce project? The code above is lacking and may not reproduce your issue on my side.